# Only one drop down button active in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am currently working on an app where I need to implement more drop down buttons. I have found a guide on how to make a drop down button, and it works like a charm. The problem is that I want the "drop down part" to hide if you press another drop down button (or somewhere else on the screen if it is possible, but that part is not necessary).

Here is a link to a part of the project with the drop down buttons.

https://github.com/Rawchris/More-drop-downs

If you want the code in here you can say so, but I thought it was better this way. If you don't understand what I want, please say so and I will try to explain it better.

Comment: is the open and close single dropdown is work properly?

Comment: yes it works please check the source @ShivamParmar

Comment: i can't see your code now but i can guide you that how can you achieve this gole ...

Comment: @ShivamParmar Why can't you see my code?

Comment: I think he is AFK now @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- add closure into `dropDownBtn` (btw this is not a correct naming please check the [link](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide))

```swift
class dropDownBtn: UIButton, dropDownProtocol {
    var didTapDropDown: ((Bool) -> Void)?
.
.
.
```

- add this closure to the end of the `override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {`

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
.
.
.
    didTapDropDown?(isOpen)
}
```

- then add these configuration to `viewDidLoad`

```swift
button1.didTapDropDown = { [unowned self] isOpened in
    if isOpened {
        self.button2.dismissDropDown()
    }
}

button2.didTapDropDown = { [unowned self] isOpened in
    if isOpened {
        self.button1.dismissDropDown()
    }
}

//Add Button to the View Controller
self.view.addSubview(button1)
self.view.addSubview(button2)
```